# Bootstrap nav interactive tablist left and right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have interactive navs with two being left-aligned ("First" and "Second") and one is right-aligned ("More"). Currently, I can switch between "First" and "Second" without problems. Yet if I select "More" I can switch back to "First" or "Second" but no longer back to "More", as it can't be deactivated.

Is there a way to either treat both tab lists as one or only use one tab list with two tabs on the left and one tab on the right?

[Js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qoh6ruwL/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav nav" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-selected="true">First</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="nav-second" aria-selected="false">Second</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto" id="nav-tab-right" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-more-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-more" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="nav-more" aria-selected="false">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <!--First tab-->
            <div class="tab-pane show active" id="nav-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-first-tab">
                <p>First!</p>
            </div>

            <!--Second tab-->
            <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-second-tab">
                <p>Second!</p>
            </div>

            <!--More tab-->
            <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-more" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-more-tab">
                <p>More!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap default JavaScript is not exactly *"magic"*, although at times it feels that way. In order to make it work, certain assumptions had to be made. One of them is that you respect the provided markup.

Which you haven't. In your case, you're not controlling the tablist from only one parent `role="tablist"` container, but from two. So you'll need to do the deselect yourself:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#navbarNavAltMarkup').on('click', '[role="tab"]', function(e) {
    $('[role="tab"].active', $(this).closest('.navbar-collapse')).each((i, el) => {
      $(el).removeClass('active show');
      $(el).attr('aria-selected', 'false');
    })
  })
});
```

See it working:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#navbarNavAltMarkup').on('click', '[role="tab"]', function(e) {
    $('[role="tab"].active', $(this).closest('.navbar-collapse')).each((i, el) => {
      $(el).removeClass('active show');
      $(el).attr('aria-selected', 'false');
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav nav" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-selected="true">First</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-second" aria-selected="false">Second</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto" id="nav-tab-right" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-more-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-more" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-more" aria-selected="false">More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <!--First tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane show active" id="nav-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-first-tab">
      <p>First!</p>
    </div>

    <!--Second tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-second-tab">
      <p>Second!</p>
    </div>

    <!--More tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-more" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-more-tab">
      <p>More!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another possible solution is to keep all the tab controls in the same tablist parent and use custom CSS for positioning them as required:

```css
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  #navbarNavAltMarkup .navbar-nav:first-child{
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  #navbarNavAltMarkup .nav-item:last-child{
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav nav" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-selected="true">First</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-second" aria-selected="false">Second</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-more-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-more" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-more" aria-selected="false">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

For thoroughness, I admit I was expecting Bootstrap 4 to be smarter. My first attempt at fixing this was to simply remove `role="tablist"` from each `.nav` and placed it on the common parent.
And ***it should have worked!***.

But if we look into [BS's source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/tab.js), we'll see they use `NAV_LIST_GROUP: '.nav, .list-group',` as list selectors, rather than `[role="tablist"]` and I find it hard to understand why.

IMHO, it's `role` that should have been used, since it already fulfills the same exact *"role"* for screen readers (it declares: somewhere in my markup you'll find a list of tab controls and each of them is marked as `role="tab"`). They (the Bootstrap team) were probably afraid novice coders will remove/omit `role` attributes and the tabs will stop working. Well, they shouldn't work when/if you remove `role` attributes. Some users rely on those attributes to read/find relevant content a little bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

One quick possible solution I found, was adding the following javascript code, that manually sets the right classes and attributes, overriding the default implementation

```html
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function () {
    $('#nav-tab').children().removeClass('active');
    $('#nav-tab').children().removeClass('show');
    $('#nav-tab').children().attr('aria-selected', 'false');
    $('#nav-tab-right').children().removeClass('active');
    $('#nav-tab-right').children().removeClass('show');
    $('#nav-tab-right').children().attr('aria-selected', 'false');
});
```